# Migrating a web store error

Tags: php, opencart

I recently changed my hosting provider and now that I uploaded the website to the new FTP I get these two errors . 
I have no idea where to look as I am a pretty unexperienced with coding.
My web store is based on opencart's final version .

Many thanks 
Lubomir

Warning: require_once(/users/bhrmwgng/public_html/system/startup.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/bhrmwgng/public_html/index.php on line 19

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/users/bhrmwgng/public_html/system/startup.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/bhrmwgng/public_html/index.php on line 19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for being so late to post an update, the problem if I remeber correctly was in the config.php, now to think of it was a simple mistake, someone unfamiliar with the basics would do.

Answer (score 0):

Please Verify all the files moved into the new Server. startup.php file in system folder is missing it seems!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using the path of your old server, look at your configuration and replace old absolute path's to the new ones.